# ArcGIS export map options

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, resolution

I have a problem with the "export map options" of ArcMap 10.2
There are only two parameters in the option window that are: general and format.
I set high dpi at 300 but the map exported has not a good resolution as I parametrized and as I wish.

Why aren't there the other parameters like pages, security, advanced?

I tried also using ArcPy but I didn't find the correct Python code.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to export a PDF?

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the export options if you are exporting to an image file. Pages, Security, and Advanced (all 3 together) are only available if exporting to a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

How large is the page you're exporting?
If it's smaller such as letter or tabloid size then 300 dpi should be fine, however if you're exporting something that's poster sized or larger you may need to increase your dpi to 450 or 600.
Also what format are you exporting in? As mentioned in the comments only exporting to PDF will include additional settings. Again however if you are exporting something very large PDF may not be your best option either, and you may want to export to a tif or jpg and then convert to PDF afterwards to preserve quality.